Using @PostMapping and @NoteEmpty together. excepted to generate parameters, but get application/json
Using @PostMapping and @NoteEmpty together. Expected to generate parameters, but get application/json
Describe the bug
Spring Boot 2.7
Using @PostMapping and @NoteEmpty together. Expected to generate parameters, but get application/json
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Operation(summary = "assoc user and roles")
@PostMapping( "/bindUserRoles")
public Result<Void> bindUserRoles(@NotNull Long userId,  @NoteEmpty List<Long> roleIds) {
    return Result.ok();
}

To Reproduce
{
    "openapi": "3.0.1",
    "info": {
      "title": "TEST API",
      "description": "TEST API",
      "contact": {
        "name": "ideaplus",
        "email": "ideaplus@example.com"
      },
      "version": "v1.0.0"
    },
    "servers": [
      {
        "url": "http://localhost:7070",
        "description": "Generated server url"
      }
    ],
    "paths": {
      "/system/user/bindUserRoles": {
        "post": {
          "tags": [
            "TEST tag"
          ],
          "summary": "assoc user and roles",
          "operationId": "bindUserRoles",
          "parameters": [
            {
              "name": "userId",
              "in": "query",
              "required": true,
              "schema": {
                "type": "integer",
                "format": "int64"
              }
            }
          ],
          "requestBody": {
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "array",
                  "items": {
                    "type": "integer",
                    "format": "int64"
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "required": true
          },
          "responses": {
            "200": {
              "description": "OK",
              "content": {
                "*/*": {
                  "schema": {
                    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/ResultVoid"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "components": {
      "ResultVoid": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "code": {
            "type": "integer",
            "format": "int32"
          },
          "msg": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "data": {
            "type": "object"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

Expected behavior
{
  "openapi": "3.0.1",
  "info": {
    "title": "TEST API",
    "description": "TEST API",
    "contact": {
      "name": "ideaplus",
      "email": "ideaplus@example.com"
    },
    "version": "v1.0.0"
  },
  "servers": [
    {
      "url": "http://localhost:7070",
      "description": "Generated server url"
    }
  ],
  "paths": {
    "/system/user/bindUserRoles": {
      "post": {
        "tags": [
          "TEST tag"
        ],
        "summary": "assoc user and roles",
        "operationId": "bindUserRoles",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "userId",
            "in": "query",
            "required": true,
            "schema": {
              "type": "integer",
              "format": "int64"
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "roleIds",
            "in": "query",
            "required": true,
            "schema": {
              "type": "array",
              "items": {
                "type": "integer",
                "format": "int64"
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK",
            "content": {
              "*/*": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/ResultVoid"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "components": {
    "ResultVoid": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "code": {
          "type": "integer",
          "format": "int32"
        },
        "msg": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "data": {
          "type": "object"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Current solutions
If there is no @NoteEmpty, or if the @RequestParam is added, the expected result will be achieved.
But I don't want to add @RequestParam annotations to each object input parameter.
Is there any other way?
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Operation(summary = "assoc user and roles")
@PostMapping( "/bindUserRoles")
public Result<Void> bindUserRoles(@NotNull Long userId,  @NoteEmpty List<Long> roleIds) {
    return Result.ok();
}

import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Operation(summary = "assoc user and roles")
@PostMapping( "/bindUserRoles")
public Result<Void> bindUserRoles(@NotNull Long userId,  @RequestParam @NoteEmpty List<Long> roleIds) {
    return Result.ok();
}

